# The Bottom of sidebar is hidden under page window

Tags: html, css, grid, overflow, bootstrap-5

I have an issue where the bottom of the sidebar is not showing. when I remove the top navbar, it works as expected. And I have tried several ways to fix it but all the solutions I have found didn't work with me.

**Is there any Idea how to fix this issue?**

This is a screenshot of the issue, where you can see that the bottom of the scrollbar is hidden under the page window:
[image: screenshot]

This is the code snippet:

```css
html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .scrollable {
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-white shadow bg-white z-2">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-primary" href="#">
          Shopping System
        </a>

        <div
          class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"
          id="navbarText"
        >
          <span class="navbar-text text-dark me-4">Welcome, User Name</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- main content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- left content -->
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- fixed sidebar -->
            <div class="col-4 border-end">
              <nav class="nav flex-column">
                <a
                  class="nav-link active mb-3 text-dark border-bottom"
                  id="v-pills-home-tab"
                  data-bs-toggle="pill"
                  data-bs-target="#v-pills-home"
                  role="button"
                  aria-controls="v-pills-home"
                  aria-selected="true"
                  >Form 1</a
                >

                <a
                  class="nav-link mb-3 text-dark border-bottom"
                  id="v-pills-profile-tab"
                  data-bs-toggle="pill"
                  data-bs-target="#v-pills-profile"
                  role="button"
                  aria-controls="v-pills-profile"
                  aria-selected="false"
                  >Form 2</a
                >
              </nav>
            </div>

            <!-- scrollable sidebar -->
            <div class="col border bg-info p-0">
              <!-- <div class="scrollable"></div> -->
              <div class="tab-content p-2 scrollable" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                <div
                  class="tab-pane fade show active"
                  id="v-pills-home"
                  role="tabpanel"
                  aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed
                  quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra
                  posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget
                  euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum
                  bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu
                  dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis.
                  Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros.
                  Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras
                  gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer
                  erat, id egestas pede nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit
                  vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet
                  massa pede eu diam. Aliquam iaculis. Fusce et ipsum et nulla
                  tristique facilisis. Donec eget sem sit amet ligula viverra
                  gravida. Etiam vehicula urna vel turpis. Suspendisse sagittis
                  ante a urna. Morbi a est quis orci consequat rutrum. Nullam
                  egestas feugiat felis. Integer adipiscing semper ligula. Nunc
                  molestie, nisl sit amet cursus convallis, sapien lectus
                  pretium metus, vitae pretium enim wisi id lectus. Donec
                  vestibulum. Etiam vel nibh. Nulla facilisi. Mauris pharetra.
                  Donec augue. Fusce ultrices, neque id dignissim ultrices,
                  tellus mauris dictum elit, vel lacinia enim metus eu nunc.
                  Proin at eros non eros adipiscing mollis. Donec semper turpis
                  sed diam. Sed consequat ligula nec tortor. Integer eget sem.
                  Ut vitae enim eu est vehicula gravida. Morbi ipsum ipsum,
                  porta nec, tempor id, auctor vitae, purus. Pellentesque neque.
                  Nulla luctus erat vitae libero. Integer nec enim. Phasellus
                  aliquam enim et tortor. Quisque aliquet, quam elementum
                  condimentum feugiat, tellus odio consectetuer wisi, vel
                  nonummy sem neque in elit. Curabitur eleifend wisi iaculis
                  ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
                  et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In non velit non ligula
                  laoreet ultrices. Praesent ultricies facilisis nisl. Vivamus
                  luctus elit sit amet mi. Phasellus pellentesque, erat eget
                  elementum volutpat, dolor nisl porta neque, vitae sodales
                  ipsum nibh in ligula. Maecenas mattis pulvinar diam. Curabitur
                  sed leo. Nulla facilisi. In vel sem. Morbi id urna in diam
                  dignissim feugiat. Proin molestie tortor eu velit. Aliquam
                  erat volutpat. Nullam ultrices, diam tempus vulputate egestas,
                  eros pede varius leo, sed imperdiet lectus est ornare odio.
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                  Proin consectetuer velit in dui. Phasellus wisi purus,
                  interdum vitae, rutrum accumsan, viverra in, velit. Sed enim
                  risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus. Aenean
                  tortor mi, imperdiet id, gravida eu, posuere eu, felis. Mauris
                  sollicitudin, turpis in hendrerit sodales, lectus ipsum
                  pellentesque ligula, sit amet scelerisque urna nibh ut arcu.
                  Aliquam in lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus
                  orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla placerat
                  aliquam wisi. Mauris viverra odio. Quisque fermentum pulvinar
                  odio. Proin posuere est vitae ligula. Etiam euismod. Cras a
                  eros. Nunc auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan
                  mauris. Etiam enim enim, elementum sed, bibendum quis, rhoncus
                  non, metus. Fusce neque dolor, adipiscing sed, consectetuer
                  et, lacinia sit amet, quam. Suspendisse wisi quam,
                  consectetuer in, blandit sed, suscipit eu, eros. Etiam ligula
                  enim, tempor ut, blandit nec, mollis eu, lectus. Nam cursus.
                  Vivamus iaculis. Aenean risus purus, pharetra in, blandit
                  quis, gravida a, turpis. Donec nisl. Aenean eget mi. Fusce
                  mattis est id diam. Phasellus faucibus interdum sapien. Duis
                  quis nunc. Sed enim. Pellentesque vel dui sed orci faucibus
                  iaculis. Suspendisse dictum magna id purus tincidunt rutrum.
                  Nulla congue. Vivamus sit amet lorem posuere dui vulputate
                  ornare. Phasellus mattis sollicitudin ligula. Duis dignissim
                  felis et urna. Integer adipiscing congue metus. Nam pede.
                  Etiam non wisi. Sed accumsan dolor ac augue. Pellentesque eget
                  lectus. Aliquam nec dolor nec tellus ornare venenatis. Nullam
                  blandit placerat sem. Curabitur quis ipsum. Mauris nisl
                  tellus, aliquet eu, suscipit eu, ullamcorper quis, magna.
                  Mauris elementum, pede at sodales vestibulum, nulla tortor
                  congue massa, quis pellentesque odio dui id est. Cras faucibus
                  augue. Suspendisse vestibulum dignissim quam. Integer vel
                  augue. Phasellus nulla purus, interdum ac, venenatis non,
                  varius rutrum, leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
                  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis a
                  eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
                  conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Fusce magna mi,
                  porttitor quis, convallis eget, sodales ac, urna. Phasellus
                  luctus venenatis
                </div>
                <div
                  class="tab-pane fade"
                  id="v-pills-profile"
                  role="tabpanel"
                  aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed
                  quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra
                  posuere sapien.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- right content -->
        <div class="col p-0">
          <div class="card border-0">
            <img
              src="https://ibb.co/K905DBS"
              style="width: 100%"
              class="card-img rounded-0 border-0"
              alt="map"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `.scrollable` class is being set to fill the height of your entire viewport, not accounting for the height of the `nav`.

I would recommend checking out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for the `calc()` function in CSS. The following CSS should solve your issue:

```css
nav {
    /* Since you're using Bootstrap, this is already being set by another
    class */
    height: 50px;
}

.scrollable {
    /* Subtract whatever the preset height of the header is */
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your scroll bar is hidden is because you have `overflow: hidden;` with the  `<nav>` and it extends past the height of the page.

I set the `nav` to `position:absolute; width:100%;` to place the `<nav>` above the `.row` and added the class `.row-ur-boat` to set `.padding-top:55px;`

Try this :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .p-2 {
            position: inherit;
            overflow: auto;
            height: inherit;
        }
        .col.border.bg-info.p-0,
        .row,
        .col-4.border-end,
        .col-4,
        .container-fluid {
            height: inherit;
        }
        .navbar.navbar-expand-lg.bg-body-white.shadow.bg-white.z-2 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .row-ur-boat {
            padding-top: 55px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-white shadow bg-white z-2">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand text-primary" href="#">
                    Shopping System
                </a>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarText">
                    <span class="navbar-text text-dark me-4">Welcome, User Name</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- main content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row row-ur-boat">
                <!-- left content -->
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- fixed sidebar -->
                        <div class="col-4 border-end">
                            <nav class="nav flex-column">
                                <a class="nav-link active mb-3 text-dark border-bottom" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-home" role="button" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Form 1</a>

                                <a class="nav-link mb-3 text-dark border-bottom" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#v-pills-profile" role="button" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Form 2</a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>

                        <!-- scrollable sidebar -->
                        <div class="col border bg-info p-0">
                            <!-- <div class="scrollable"></div> -->
                            <div class="tab-content p-2 scrollable" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab" tabindex="0">
                                    vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper,
                                    lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed,
                                    blandit a, eros. Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id egestas pede nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit
                                    vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet massa pede eu diam. Aliquam iaculis. Fusce et ipsum et nulla tristique facilisis. Donec eget sem sit amet ligula viverra gravida. Etiam
                                    vehicula urna vel turpis. Suspendisse sagittis ante a urna. Morbi a est quis orci consequat rutrum. Nullam egestas feugiat felis. Integer adipiscing semper ligula. Nunc molestie, nisl sit amet cursus
                                    convallis, sapien lectus pretium metus, vitae pretium enim wisi id lectus. Donec vestibulum. Etiam vel nibh. Nulla facilisi. Mauris pharetra. Donec augue. Fusce ultrices, neque id dignissim ultrices,
                                    tellus mauris dictum elit, vel lacinia enim metus eu nunc. Proin at eros non eros adipiscing mollis. Donec semper turpis sed diam. Sed consequat ligula nec tortor. Integer eget sem. Ut vitae enim eu est
                                    vehicula gravida. Morbi ipsum ipsum, porta nec, tempor id, auctor vitae, purus. Pellentesque neque. Nulla luctus erat vitae libero. Integer nec enim. Phasellus aliquam enim et tortor. Quisque aliquet,
                                    quam elementum condimentum feugiat, tellus odio consectetuer wisi, vel nonummy sem neque in elit. Curabitur eleifend wisi iaculis ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
                                    malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In non velit non ligula laoreet ultrices. Praesent ultricies facilisis nisl. Vivamus luctus elit sit amet mi. Phasellus pellentesque, erat eget elementum volutpat, dolor
                                    nisl porta neque, vitae sodales ipsum nibh in ligula. Maecenas mattis pulvinar diam. Curabitur sed leo. Nulla facilisi. In vel sem. Morbi id urna in diam dignissim feugiat. Proin molestie tortor eu velit.
                                    Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ultrices, diam tempus vulputate egestas, eros pede varius leo, sed imperdiet lectus est ornare odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin
                                    consectetuer velit in dui. Phasellus wisi purus, interdum vitae, rutrum accumsan, viverra in, velit. Sed enim risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus. Aenean tortor mi, imperdiet id, gravida
                                    eu, posuere eu, felis. Mauris sollicitudin, turpis in hendrerit sodales, lectus ipsum pellentesque ligula, sit amet scelerisque urna nibh ut arcu. Aliquam in lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
                                    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla placerat aliquam wisi. Mauris viverra odio. Quisque fermentum pulvinar odio. Proin posuere est vitae ligula. Etiam euismod. Cras a eros. Nunc
                                    auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan mauris. Etiam enim enim, elementum sed, bibendum quis, rhoncus non, metus. Fusce neque dolor, adipiscing sed, consectetuer et, lacinia sit amet, quam.
                                    Suspendisse wisi quam, consectetuer in, blandit sed, suscipit eu, eros. Etiam ligula enim, tempor ut, blandit nec, mollis eu, lectus. Nam cursus. Vivamus iaculis. Aenean risus purus, pharetra in, blandit
                                    quis, gravida a, turpis. Donec nisl. Aenean eget mi. Fusce mattis est id diam. Phasellus faucibus interdum sapien. Duis quis nunc. Sed enim. Pellentesque vel dui sed orci faucibus iaculis. Suspendisse
                                    dictum magna id purus tincidunt rutrum. Nulla congue. Vivamus sit amet lorem posuere dui vulputate ornare. Phasellus mattis sollicitudin ligula. Duis dignissim felis et urna. Integer adipiscing congue
                                    metus. Nam pede. Etiam non wisi. Sed accumsan dolor ac augue. Pellentesque eget lectus. Aliquam nec dolor nec tellus ornare venenatis. Nullam blandit placerat sem. Curabitur quis ipsum. Mauris nisl
                                    tellus, aliquet eu, suscipit eu, ullamcorper quis, magna. Mauris elementum, pede at sodales vestibulum, nulla tortor congue massa, quis pellentesque odio dui id est. Cras faucibus augue. Suspendisse
                                    vestibulum dignissim quam. Integer vel augue. Phasellus nulla purus, interdum ac, venenatis non, varius rutrum, leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
                                    egestas. Duis a eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Fusce magna mi, porttitor quis, convallis eget, sodales ac, urna. Phasellus luctus
                                    venenatis
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab" tabindex="0">
                                    vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- right content -->
                <div class="col p-0">
                    <div class="card border-0">
                        <img src="https://ibb.co/K905DBS" style="width: 100%;" class="card-img rounded-0 border-0" alt="map" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```